# The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, extension-methods

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u195296372/public_html/include/header.php on line 21

I had this error in my header.

This is the code (line 21 and 22):

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect to the database."); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select the database.");
```

Comment: version of php is?

Comment: and you're not mixing different mysql apis such as mysqli_ and/or pdo, right?

Comment: As the message says - [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) functions are now deprecated and should be avoided. Use either [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: It's 5.6! And, nope. Just mysql :D

Comment: The [deprecation followed by removal](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) (in PHP 7.0) of the old mysql PHP extension is a known and documented event for [more than 3 years](http://php.net/supported-versions.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli` instead.

Your code would look like this:

```php
mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect to the database.");
mysqli_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select the database.");
```

Or, in object-oriented style:

```php
$mysqli = new mysqli("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    die("database connection failed.");
}
```

Then you can do queries like this:

```php
$result = $mysqli->query("[SQL query]");
```

[MySqli documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I added more details.

Comment: Why not return the actual errors? Your `die()` statements won't be helpful if something fails.